# Google analytics pods giving error in xcode 6.4

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, google-analytics

I have added Google Analytics in my **main project** same as my Analytics's **demo project** I have followed as it is mentioned in [Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/), **demo project** is working fine however I am getting following error

> **Lexical or preprocessor issue** 
> 'Google/Analytics.h' file not found

while building **main project**.
on line in `AppDelegate.h`

```
#import <Google/Analytics.h>
```

*Main project is developed in  below xcode 6.4 version* so it is having Prefix(.pch) file, in which contain following code

```
#import <Availability.h>

#ifndef __IPHONE_5_0
#warning "This project uses features only available in iOS SDK 5.0 and later."
#endif

#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import "AppDelegate.h"
#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

**Option-1**

actual error is your framework header not found in `User header paths` , so the header files not found was from cocoapods, so  re-installed the cocoapods using `pod install` and then try

**Option-2**

1. Go the Google/AnalyticsSDK directory, select Google/AnalyticsSDK.framework, right click and press get info then copy the file path.(something like : /Users/macbook/Documents/GoogleSDK)
2. Go to "Build Settings" in Xcode, and under "Search Paths" there is a "Framework Search Paths" item. Double-click it and paste the file path that you just copied.
3. Be aware this setting exists both under 'Project' and 'Target', so paste it in both places.
4. Clean project and build. This time it should work.

**Option-3**

```
#import <Availability.h>

#ifndef __IPHONE_5_0
#warning "This project uses features only available in iOS SDK 5.0 and later."
#endif

#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import "AppDelegate.h"
    #import <Google/Analytics.h> // add your framework here
   
#endif
```

**Option-4**

Go to "Build Settings" in Xcode, and under "Search Paths" there is a "Framework Search Paths" item.  Double-click it and add a new search path: `.` and make it recursive.  Clean and build.

This assumes that your framework is stored somewhere inside your project directory.  If not, change the new search path as needed.

Comment: Yes, I tried the same but it is not working. before asking the question I tried 4-5 times with different method but nothing is working.

Comment: @Sujay -- check the updated answer', this will occur in many scenarios we can find in step by step, sorry for delay reply